# Input Value doesn't change when selecting an option in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using [react-select](https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/) to define a select input control in my react application. This is how I'm using the component:

```
<Select
   onChange={function(e) {console.log(e)}}
   options={[
      {value: "sf", label: "San Francisco"},
      {value: "nyc", label: "New York City"}
   ]}
></Select>
```

Before selecting any option I see a `Select...` placeholder as the input value. This doesn't change after selecting an option: the input value doesn't change and the `Select...` placeholder appears to be the selected "option".

Is there something wrong with how I'm using the component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the `Select` value in `state` variable, and `logChange` function will return an `object`, assign the `value` of that `object` to state variable, it will work, Check this code:

```js
class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(){
     super();
     this.state = {value: ''}
  }
   
  logChange(val) {
    console.log("Selected: " + val.value);
    this.setState({value: val.value});
  }

  render(){
    var options = [
       {value: 'one', label: 'One' },
       {value: 'two', label: 'Two' } 
    ];
    return(
      
      <Select
          name="form-field-name"
          value={this.state.value}
          options={options}
          onChange={this.logChange.bind(this)}
      />
      
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/classnames/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-input-autosize/dist/react-input-autosize.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-select/dist/react-select.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-select/dist/react-select.css">

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it obviously works, though I think something doesn't look right in there. Why should I be the one managing the internal state of the Select component? Wouldn't it be more productive if the Select component were responsible to set the input value when an option is being selected? Besides being ugly, the choice not to do so has a performance cost: whenever the user selects an option, the whole application must be re-rendered (because the global state changes) instead of only re-rendering the Select component. Maybe there's a better way?